# OpenCV(4.1.2) error: (-215:Assertion failed) !ssize.empty() in function 'cv::resize'

Tags: python, opencv, computer-vision

I am recieving this error when running this line of code:

```
img = cv2.resize(img, (224,224))
```

> OpenCV(4.1.2) C:\projects\opencv-python\opencv\modules\imgproc\src\resize.cpp:3720: error: (-215:Assertion failed) !ssize.empty() in function 'cv::resize'

Answer (score 13, accepted):

Your `img` variable is empty, you probably didn't load the image correctly. Try printing your `img.shape` after you load your image. Then have a look at the path you specified, there is probably something wrong with it. (Either you misspelled something or the file doesn't exist in that directory)

Answer (score -2):

```
frame = cv2.resize(frame,(224,224),fx=0,fy=0, interpolation = cv2.INTER_CUBIC)
```

I've changed my code to this and it works for me.

Comment: that can't possibly have fixed it because `!ssize.empty()` talks about the size of the input image, which is `frame`.