# cv2.error: OpenCV(4.5.2) resize.cpp:4051: error: (-215:Assertion failed) !ssize.empty() in function 'cv::resize'

Tags: python, opencv, computer-vision

I am receiving this error when running this line of code :

```
pixels.append( cv2.resize(cv2.imread(raw_folder  + folder +"/" + file),dsize=(128,128)))**
```

Error:

```
cv2.error: OpenCV(4.5.2) C:\Users\runneradmin\AppData\Local\Temp\pip-req-build-vi271kac\opencv\modules\imgproc\src\resize.cpp:4051: 
error: (-215:Assertion failed) !ssize.empty() in function 'cv::resize'
```

Comment: you may have common problem: when `CV2` can't read file then it doesn't raise error but it returns `None` and now you try to resize `None` - empty image - and this shows `!ssize.empty()`. You should first read image, next check if you get `None` and next try to resize it.

Comment: btw: first you should check if `raw_folder + folder +"/" + file` create correct path and if you can open it in any other program. Maybe you forgot some `/` in path (ie. between `raw_folder ` and `folder`) or you create path to not existing file.

Comment: Hi, welcome to Stack Overflow! Does this answer your question? [OpenCV(4.1.2) error: (-215:Assertion failed) !ssize.empty() in function 'cv::resize'](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/62531965/opencv4-1-2-error-215assertion-failed-ssize-empty-in-function-cvres) Let me know if it doesn't :)

Answer (score 10):

You may have common problem: when CV2 can't read file then it doesn't raise error but it returns `None` and now you try to resize `None` - empty image - and this shows `!ssize.empty()`.

You should first read image, next check if you get `None` and next try to resize it.

You should check if `raw_folder + folder +"/" + file` creates correct path and if you can open it in any other program. Maybe you forgot some `/` in path (ie. between `raw_folder` and `folder`) or forgot file extension or you create path to not existing file.

```
path = os.path.join(raw_folder, folder, file)
print('[DEBUG] path:', path)

img = cv2.imread(path)

if img is None:
    print('Wrong path:', path)
else:
    img = cv2.resize(img, dsize=(128,128))
    pixels.append(img)
```

Answer (score 0):

Another situation that lead to this error was to input an image of the wrong shape. I had an RGB image of shape (3, 540, 960) and got the misleading 'ssize is not empty'. Changing the shape to (540, 960, 3) fixed my problem.

Comment: you better not reshape that data because that will jumble all the information. you need to *transpose*. -- this question does not show enough information to conclude that *this* could have been the issue. in fact, what is given, indicates that this could not have been the issue. your answer answers a _different_ question but not this one.

Comment: It was the issue for me; the error message is just inaccurate.

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/help/self-answer you can create a question and answer it yourself.

Comment: No, my claim is that, depending on OPs file contents, he could have gotten this error message from the posted code.

Comment: you're reaching. OP could not. OP used `cv.imread`, which always returns `(h,w,c)` order, never `(c,h,w)`. there's no way to justify this answer under this question. how did **you** get (c,h,w) order? you could not have used cv.imread

Comment: I'm not reaching, I'm wrong :) I was reading with a different function. Anyways; I leave this here because next time I google this error message it's nice to have a more exhaustive list of reasons pop up