# How to resize frame in OpenCV on python without running into an error?

Tags: python, opencv, resize

I was making a project on face Recogniser using python. I imported OpenCV and another .py file(simple_facerec) and wrote the code. I ran into the error bellow

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "c:/face.py", line 12, in <module>
    face_locations, face_names = sfr.detect_known_faces(frame)
  File "c:\simple_facerec.py", line 43, in detect_known_faces
    small_frame = cv2.resize(frame, (0,0), fx=self.frame_resizing, fy=self.frame_resizing)
cv2.error: OpenCV(4.5.5) D:\a\opencv-python\opencv-python\opencv\modules\imgproc\src\resize.cpp:4052: error: (-215:Assertion failed) !ssize.empty() in function 'cv::resize'
```

I think the error was basically in simple_facerec. The line that ran into error is below.

```
    def detect_known_faces(self, frame):
        small_frame = cv2.resize(frame, (0,0), fx=self.frame_resizing, fy=self.frame_resizing)
        # Find all the faces and face encodings in the current frame of video
        # Convert the image from BGR color (which OpenCV uses) to RGB color (which face_recognition uses)
        rgb_small_frame = cv2.cvtColor(frame, cv2.COLOR_BGR2RGB)
        face_locations = face_recognition.face_locations(rgb_small_frame)
        face_encodings = face_recognition.face_encodings(rgb_small_frame, face_locations)
```

Can Someone please give me a solution for this?

Comment: Have a look at https://stackoverflow.com/questions/62531965/opencv4-1-2-error-215assertion-failed-ssize-empty-in-function-cvres?rq=1

Comment: `frame is None` when it shouldn't be. you aren't showing enough code to see why.

Comment: I made the project with reference to the youtube video and blog by pysource

Answer (score 0):

The value for `dsize` [cannot be zero](https://docs.opencv.org/3.4/da/d54/group__imgproc__transform.html#:%7E:text=output%20image%20size%3B%20if%20it%20equals%20zero%20(None%20in%20Python)%2C%20it%20is%20computed%20as), if you want to use `fx` and `fy` to resize an image, dsize must be `None`:

```
def detect_known_faces(self, frame):
    small_frame = cv2.resize(frame, None, fx=self.frame_resizing, fy=self.frame_resizing)
    # Find all the faces and face encodings in the current frame of video
    # Convert the image from BGR color (which OpenCV uses) to RGB color (which face_recognition uses)
    rgb_small_frame = cv2.cvtColor(frame, cv2.COLOR_BGR2RGB)
    face_locations = face_recognition.face_locations(rgb_small_frame)
    face_encodings = face_recognition.face_encodings(rgb_small_frame, face_locations)
```

Comment: I am still running into the same error

Comment: @ShriyaKumari If you remove the `small_frame = cv2.resize(frame, None, fx=self.frame_resizing, fy=self.frame_resizing)` line, does the problem persist?

Comment: No it doesn't as after resizing it I have to turn the image into RGB format. This is because OpenCV uses BGR color and after finding the faces in the image face_recognition has to identify them and face_recognition uses RGB. so I basically need to resize it for this purpose.