# error: (-215:Assertion failed) size.width>0 && size.height>0 in function 'imshow' when use cv2.resize method

Tags: python, opencv, image-processing

Why is the output of `cv2.resize` here `None`?

```
import cv2
img = cv2.imread("data/sample.jpg")
if img is not None:
    img1 = cv2.resize(img, (500, 500))
    cv2.imshow("My demo", img1)
else:
    print("Unable to load image")
```

I am getting this error message:

> cv2.error: OpenCV(4.6.0) /Users/xperience/actions-runner/_work/opencv-python/opencv-python/opencv/modules/highgui/src/window.cpp:967: error: (-215:Assertion failed) size.width>0 && size.height>0 in function 'imshow'

Comment: Did I get your question right? You see `img1` being None? That shouldn't be happening...

Comment: img1 getting None so imshow generating this  error: (-215:Assertion failed). i dont understand why img1 getting None here

Comment: Use relative path sample.jpg. If the file is in currently folder.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [OpenCV(4.1.2) error: (-215:Assertion failed) !ssize.empty() in function 'cv::resize'](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/62531965/opencv4-1-2-error-215assertion-failed-ssize-empty-in-function-cvres)

Answer (score 0):

It works for me. However, you can always fall back to plt.imshow

```
import cv2
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
img = cv2.imread("download.png")
if img is not None:  
    img1 = cv2.resize(img, (200, 200))
    plt.imshow(img1),plt.show()
    cv2.imshow("name", img1)
    cv2.waitKey(1000)
else:
    print("Unable to load image")
```